# How to cleanly manage classes and components with multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#

I have a **Car** which is an *ICar*, an *IFuelPowered* and an *IVehicle*

My Car contains a **CarData** class, which is an *ICarData*, an *IFuelPoweredData*, and an *IVehicleData*

Whilst the Car class holds behaviour logic, the data interfaces present various properties, for example:

ICarData:

- Brand

IFuelPoweredData:

- TankSize

IVehicleData

- MaxSpeed

Within the Car class, I'd like to include only ICarData as a property (which inherits from the IFuelPoweredData and IVehicleData interfaces, and therefore complies with all these contracts)

But instead I have to do this:

```
IVehicleData IVehicle.Data => Data;
IFuelPoweredData IFuelPowered.Data => Data;
public ICarData Data { get; }
```

Else the compiler complains the interfaces on IFuelPowered and IVehicle are not implemented. This is because for example, IFuelPowered has IFuelPoweredData on its interface.

This confuses me because Car does have a property of ICarData (which itself implements IFuelPoweredData and IVehicleData).

Is there a cleaner approach to this style of problem?

Comment: This is an X/Y Problem rooted in your domain-modelling, so giving us toy examples that are not representative of your project are not helpful. Please show us your **actual** types/classes/interfaces and their members, and also please explain _why_ you have this set-up in the first place.

Comment: I think you make a good point, is there an official term for such an X/Y problem? Sadly I'm not able to share full code but in my case this relates to separating behaviour from data (hence the two sets of classes) - combining behaviour and data into a single class would result in it being too large

Comment: You're misapplying the _"separating behaviour from data"_ concept - also, I don't believe it's possible to separate the two. I think you're being too eager in _selectively_ applying loosely defined maxims in the philosophy of programming... Let's start at the _very top_ with the fundamental question: "what problem are you trying to solve?" (and a `class` "being too large" is not an adequate problem statement).

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement `IFuelPoweredData` and `IVehicleData` in `ICarData`.

```
public interface ICarData : IFuelPoweredData, IVehicleData
{
    //Contents of interface
}
```

The you will only need an `ICarData` property in your `Car` class.

Comment: Apologies I may have not given the full picture - for example ICarData does already implement IFuelPoweredData. But Car complains because it implements IFuelPowered, but does not implement IFuelPoweredData (which IFuelPowered demands). This is despite Car implementing ICarData (which in turn implements IFuelPoweredData)

Comment: I think it's probably to do with how and where you've defined your interfaces in that case - you'd need to show the code.